# may be boost ssl handshake function have some memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I got memory leak problem in my code.
when i call socket.handshake() functions, 
and then exit main thread, i got memory leak. 

but, remove 'socket.handshake' and then 
run & exit main thread, memory leak probleam is disappeared.

**1. sample code : memory leak**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost;

void ThSslEchoClient()
{
    try
    {
        asio::io_service ios;
        asio::ssl::context context(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);

        context.set_options(
            asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds  
            | asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2  
            | asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);

        asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(ios, context);
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint host(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 13);

        socket.lowest_layer().connect(host, ec);
        // REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINE FOR COMPARISON
        socket.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client, ec);

        if (ec)
            throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
    }
    catch (std::exception& _e)
    {
        std::cerr << _e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void TestBoostAsioSslEchoClient()
{
    boost::thread_group tg;

    tg.create_thread(ThSslEchoClient);
    tg.join_all();
}
```

**2. sample code : no memory leak.**
(just remove 'socket.handshake')

```
        // REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINE FOR COMPARISON
        //socket.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client, ec);
```

I don't know where is wrong.
please help me.

Comment: how did you determine there is a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

I see no difference on my PC.

I fake a little server on port 13:

```
while true; do date | sudo netcat -l -p 13; done
```

I run the program:

```
make && valgrind ./test
```

Output without handshake:

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ valgrind ./test
==15878== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15878== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15878== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15878== Command: ./test
==15878== 
==15878== 
==15878== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15878==     in use at exit: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==15878==   total heap usage: 3,348 allocs, 3,346 frees, 207,156 bytes allocated
==15878== 
==15878== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15878==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15878==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15878==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15878==    still reachable: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==15878==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15878== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==15878== 
==15878== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15878== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

With handshake, it prints:

```
unkn protocol
```

Leaks reported *with* handshake:

```
140 ==16017== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
141 ==16017==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
142 ==16017==    by 0x60031FF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
154 ==16017== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
155 ==16017==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
156 ==16017==    by 0x60031FF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
168 ==16017== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
169 ==16017==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
170 ==16017==    by 0x60031FF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
182 ==16017== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
183 ==16017==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
184 ==16017==    by 0x60031FF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
196 ==16017== 176 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
197 ==16017==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
198 ==16017==    by 0x60031FF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
210 ==16017== 600 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
211 ==16017==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
212 ==16017==    by 0x60031FF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
228 ==16017==    still reachable: 992 bytes in 6 blocks
229 ==16017==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
230 ==16017==
```

As you can see, the "leaks" are internal to the crypto lib (part of openssl) and are likely false alerts.

Comment: thanks, but my working environemt is windows. and running sample code under visual studio 2012, then alerts some memory leak. well just ignore it?

Comment: please test like this 
===============================
boost::thread_group tg;

tg.create_thread(ThSslEchoClient);
tg.join_all();
===============================

Comment: @user2666399 What makes you think I altered the test?! Also, I suggest you find a comparable tool to report what memory was leaked for your platform. My exepectation is 99% that it will have the same source (probably some crypto RNG state that gets thread-local initialization and doesn't get freed)

Comment: I think libcrypto has memory leak reporting builtin. Try `CRYPTO_memcheck_ctrl(CRYPTO_MEM_CHECK_ON);` and then later on (at exit) `CRYPTO_mem_leaks(stderr);`

Comment: Anyways, the extra leaks completely disappear if you connect to a port that has an actuall SSL server listening.

Comment: first. may be test environemt is different, (my test env is win32, visual studio 2010).
second. may be you are not using boost::thread_group class.

Comment: @user2666399 Maybe I am using thread_group. **What makes you think I altered the test?!**. Of course the platform is different. I'm trying to help.

Comment: @user2666399 One more idea: try compiling ASIO as non-header only (BOOST_ASIO_HEADER_ONLY). It's quite possible that this changes the way in which the RTL will destruct the `openssl_init` global (?)